Xcode 16 crashes when opening XIB or Storyboard files after update
Since updating to Xcode 16, I'm experiencing a critical issue with my iOS project. Whenever I try to access a XIB or Storyboard file, Xcode crashes instantly. I can only access the XIB files by viewing them as code; attempting to open them in Interface Builder causes a crash. I also cannot create new Storyboard or XIB files because creating them causes Xcode to crash as well.
Also, I can open my xib alone in xcode, without opening the project, and in this case, it's working but useless.
Here is the crash report
Process:               Xcode [50503]
Version:               16.0 (23051)
...
Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 6 Abort trap: 6
Terminating Process:   Xcode [50503]
Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Application Specific Signatures:
!proxy || proxy.isAlive

Thread 19 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: IB.ExecutionQueue.IBCocoaTouchToolManager


I Checked and tried to modify Version Numbers in XIB and Storyboard Files.
I Performed a clean build.
I Deleted Derived Data.
I updated dependencies and cocoapods
I Uninstalled Xcode 16 and reinstalled it.

Submit your bug report about this problem to Apple. There is nothing we can do about this problem.

I was asking in case someone solve this problem. already submit it to apple

Could you share the feedback id?

Of  course :  FB15314055 (Xcode 16 crashes when opening XIB or Storyboard files after update)

I had this bug a long time ago (on a different Xcode version), because I renamed my "Home" folder a while back, renaming it from "name" to "Name", everything worked fine, except reading theses xib/storyboard files in Xcode.

I only changed the bundle ID, maybe this is the problem ?? thank for your answer. i will check that :D

OK I SOLVED THE PROBLEM. my custom fonts, and the pod "google sign in" were making the app crash. if i remove both, it's working. if i remove only one of them, it's not working. i tried with every pods and files in my project

Update to Xcode 16.2. They fix this problem.

I had an issue when using SourceTree to copy apps, but I fixed it by cloning an app via URL in Xcode. When using Xcode’s 'clone from URL' feature, it asks for permission, and after that, my issue was resolved.

I don't see how this answer is relevant to the original question.
